Impossible to play a video with the maximum width available keeping the video's aspect ratio
I am trying to play a video on a view, using the maximum width possible, keeping the video aspect ratio.
Apple recommends this code:
import SwiftUI
import AVKit


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var player = AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video2",
                                                      withExtension: "m4v")!)
    @State var isPlaying: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VideoPlayer(player: player)
                .frame(width: 320, height: 180, alignment: .center)


            Button {
                isPlaying ? player.pause() : player.play()
                isPlaying.toggle()
                player.seek(to: .zero)
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: isPlaying ? "stop" : "play")
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }       
}

this code has a nonsensical line
.frame(width: 320, height: 180, alignment: .center)

This supposes you know the video dimensions. If you omit this line the video view will simply not show.
Then I tried this:
var body: some View {
  ZStack{
    Color.clear
      .allowsHitTesting(false)
      .readSize { size in
        self.videoSize = size
      }
  
  VideoPlayer(player: player)
    .frame(width: videoSize.width,
           height:videoSize.height,
           alignment: .center)
  
    .onAppear {
      if let player {
        player.play()
      }
    }
}


extension View {
  
  public func readSize(onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
    background(
      GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
        ViewSizePreferenceSetter(size: geometryProxy.size)
          .equatable()
      }
    )
    .onPreferenceChange(ViewSizePreferenceKey.self,
                        perform: onChange)
  }

}

My idea was to put a clear view on a ZStack hoping it will fill the view space faster than the video and could be used to determine at least the view width. But this is not working.
Do not waste your time suggesting
.frame(maxWidth:.infinity, maxHeight:.infinity)

the whole thing crashes.
For heaven's sake. How do I show a video using the maximum width possible, keeping the video proportional?

If the video dimensions would be known then you could use .aspectRatio(computedAspectRatio, contentMode: .fit). This post might help for getting the dimensions: Swift - How to get video dimension?

VideoPlayer does this already. The fact that the player doesn’t show is the issue. What is affecting the layout that is taking up all the space?

@loremipsum I have disabled everything that is on the view with the video. Video is still not showing and not even playing.

If you put just the player in the view does it show in canvas? Or simulator. Run just the player not the whole app.

@BenzyNeez Thanks to Apple the code to get the video size is now asynchronous, even for videos in the bundle. This creates a problem because updating the view from that async thread creates a warning of thread priority that I was not able to solve.

@loremipsum no, it is not showing.

that is very odd. VideoPlayer takes up all available space by design

can you try it on your end? this will be better.
